# How to use grep function in R to find the correlation based on sample names

Tags: r

I have two data frames that has information about genes. Both of these data frames has the same dimensions (20,000 rows x 50 columns). I have another file called info contains the matched subject names between those data frames. I want to grep the names from the file (info) to find the correlation coefficient between the matched subjects. here is example of those files:

```
df1
gene_name    loc1  loc2 .........  loc50
gene1        1        23              25
gene2        24       15              67

df2
gene_name    loc1  loc2 .........  loc50
gene1        21       31              55
gene2        2       65              89

info file
subject     loc_in_df1   loc_in_df2
1                loc1          loc2
2                loc3          loc46
```

Comment: I don't get it, can you post an expected output based on your examples?

Comment: @ user6617454. I edited the example for more clarification. What I want here is to find the matched colnames in both df1 and df2 based on the info file, then find the correlation coefficient between those two columns. The expected results that having column has 50 corr coefficients on it.

Answer (score 0):

try something like the following

first build up a `df` with your columns pulled from `df1` and `df2` according to the info file

```
df <- cbind(df1[, info$loc_in_df1],df2[, info$loc_in_df2])
```

and

```
cor = apply(df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) return(cor.test(x[1:50], x[51:100])$estimate))
```

the 1:50 and 51:100 is assuming that you have 50 pairings in your info file but it's all just guessing as you didn't provide a reproducible sample